# Call to undefined function mysql_connect() .when i want to insert image on my php page

Tags: php

```
<html>
<Body>
<?php
  mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
  mysql_select_db("school_images");
  $res=mysql_query("select *from table1");

  echo "<table>";
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
  {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>"?> <img src="<?php echo $row[" images1 "]; ?>" height="100" width="100"> <?php echo "</td>";
    echo "</td>";echo $row["name"];echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
  } 
  echo "</table>";

</Body>
</html>
?>
```

the file is saved as  school_images

and when i type localhost/PROJECT/school_images.php

Answer (score 0):

You need to include `mysql`'s extension on your PHP installation.

If you're on a DEBIAN BASED LINUX (Ubuntu, Mint):

```
$ sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
```

If you're on a RPM/YUM BASED LINUX (RedHat, Fedora, CentOS):

```
# yum install php-mysql
```

Then restart Apache and try again.